# How can I fix Networkx reading files stop from crashing my code? Loading too many files

Tags: python, networkx

I have some code here using Networkx on python 2.7 but I guess the folder with files that I am using is too large so my program is getting killed.

How can I fix this so that it can accept larger amounts of files in folders? I assume this is a OS limit.

```
def countSubgraphs(graph_dir):
    graph_files = []
    dirFiles = listdir(graph_dir)
    dirFiles.sort()
    sorted(dirFiles)

    for files in dirFiles:
        graph_files.append(files)

    #It is breaking below
    the_graphs = [nx.read_edgelist(join(graph_dir, f), create_using=nx.DiGraph()) for f in graph_files]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you watching your memory while doing this?

Comment: @warped No I'm not. I assume I am running out of memory, but I've had other similar issues with like copying files from one folder to another and I've been able to fix it using a different command.

Comment: What are the nodetypes?  Are they `int`s?  By default networkx will read them in as strings, so you may be able to save a lot of memory by using the `nodetype` optional argument in `read_edgelist`.

Comment: @Joel I need them to be a string

Comment: How many edges/nodes are there in the graphs?  And can you give us a few example node names?